# GLES20 How to get global position of vertex after translating and rotating it

Tags: android, gles20

I have a vertex (Which i will not be showing/rendering in the scene)

```
float vertex[] = {
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

And i have a mesh, which i have translated and rotated using:

```
Matrix.translateM(World.mModelMatrix, tmOffset, globalPositionX, globalPositionY, globalPositionZ);


Matrix.rotateM(World.mModelMatrix, rmOffset, globalRotationZ, 0, 0, 1);
Matrix.rotateM(World.mModelMatrix, rmOffset, globalRotationY, 0, 1, 0);
Matrix.rotateM(World.mModelMatrix, rmOffset, globalRotationX, 1, 0, 0);
```

How can apply those translations and rotations to the vertex, and get its global position (x,y,z) after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Matrix.multiplyMV`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#multiplyMV(float[],%20int,%20float[],%20int,%20float[],%20int)) method:

```
float vertex[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
float result[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

Matrix.multiplyMV(result, 0, matrix, 0, vertex, 0);
```

Note, that you will have to add a homogeneous coordinate to your vector to make it work.

Comment: is there a way to add multiple vertices, instead of looping one by one?

Comment: Not that I would know, but I'm not very experienced with android.